# Setup phone HTTP Proxy for WIFI networks on 1.x and 2.x Android devices

Tags: android, proxy, wifi

I would like to know if it's possible to setup an HTTP Proxy for Wifi networks. 
I managed to setup the proxy (calling the "com.android.settings.ProxySelector" activity by code or using an app like Any Cut) but when I'm connected to the Wifi it seems that the proxy settings are ignored (I'm trying with multiple "default" apps like browser, maps, ...)

Sometimes it seems that the settings is read correctly by the browser and the proxy works without problems, but it seems more like a bug on the app (because is really hard to reproduce it). Anyone here that have clear ideas about this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to set proxy at app level separately by developers. Google doesn't seem to have any good solution to this problem. you may find this link useful: http://android-proxy.blogspot.com/

Comment: It links to here [http://issue1273.blogspot.com/](http://issue1273.blogspot.com/), that it's actually my blog. :(

Answer (score 0):

may be this will work.
[Set WiFi proxy without rooting phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431345/set-wifi-proxy-without-rooting-phone)

if u only need a browser, Opera browser is a good solution. it contains proxy settings (type opera:config in the address bar)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I was looking for a solution more integrated in the Android environment.

Answer (score -1):

**You can do this for Android's default browser too.** 
There's a setting available from Android 4 and up. Here is the step by step guide on how to do it with screenshots. No need to root.
http://mobilebroadband.gishan.net/entry/84/wi-fi-proxy-settings-for-android